# Azure SQL DMV procedures slow

Tags: sql-server, azure, dmv

I tried to use [Azure SQL Performance metrics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-introduces-new-near-real-time-performance-metrics/) and for me they are running very slow and consume lots of CPU (up 100%).

Example takes 4 minutes to execute, CPU 100%

```
SELECT * FROM sys.resource_stats WHERE database_name = 'db1' AND start_time > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Example instant, CPU 80%

```
SELECT end_time, avg_cpu_percent FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
```

I want to monitor DB as often as possible, but these monitoring queries kill all statistics.

1. Any ideas why it might take so long?
2. Are there any other ways to get stats from Azure SQL?

Comment: I suspect these DMVs don't support predicate push-down, which means it is going to enumerate stats for all of the databases on the instance, and then filter out all but yours.

Comment: The second query is running on the database. It is fast, but still consume CPU a lot.

Comment: How about adding OPTION (MAXDOP 1)?

Comment: MAXDOP 1 did not help.